# Twitter bootstrap modals & Ajax?

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap

I am using [Twitter bootstrap modals](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals) To load data from a table.

Here is my HTML code.

```
<tr>
....
<td> <a href="http://google.com">Text</a> </td>
....
</tr>
```

and this is the Modal div at the end of the page like so

```
<div id="modal"></div>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is by clicking the link inside the cell I want to contents of the modal to be updated & then after it finishes updating to open the modal automatically. Here is what I tried.

```
$('td').on('click','a',function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');

        $('#modal').load(href,function(){
            $(this).modal({
                keyboard:true,
                backdrop:true
              });
        });
```

It doesn't give me any errors & actually the HTML gets loaded successfully in the Modal div but it doesn't load the modal after updating the HTML it needs another "Click"?! & I don't know why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried

```
$(this).modal('show');
```

right after instantiating the modal ?

Comment: $(this).modal({
        keyboard:true,
        backdrop:true,
        show: true
    });

this worked, Thanks

Answer (score 9):

This is working for me :

```
$('div#modal').load(url,function(){
    $(this).modal({
        keyboard:true,
        backdrop:true
    });
}).modal('show');
```

But the URL provided should output a proper modal like this:

```
<div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
        <h3>Modal header</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body…</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn">Close</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried:

```
$('td a').on('click', function(){ 
 ...
})
```